# How can I install libgl1-mesa-glx

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to install OpenCPN, a navigation and chart program. The install guide recommend this:

> It is also possible to install the package via dpkg or rpm, on the condition that all dependencies are met.To make sure that this is the case on Ubuntu, open a terminal window to get a command line, (Applications->Accessories->Terminal) and copy and paste the following line: `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxbase2.8-0 wx-common libglu1-mesa libgl1-mesa-glx zlib1g bzip2 gpsd gpsd-clients xcalib libportaudio2`. Then proceed with the commands below.

I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxbase2.8-0 wx-common libglu1-mesa libgl1-mesa-glx zlib1g bzip2 gpsd gpsd-clients xcalib libportaudio2
```

in the terminal and got this:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree 
 Reading state information... Done
 bzip2 is already the newest version.
 libportaudio2 is already the newest version.
 libportaudio2 set to manually installed.
 zlib1g is already the newest version.
 xcalib is already the newest version.
 libglu1-mesa is already the newest version.
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help resolve the situation:
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7)
 Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.2)
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do now to fix the problem with `libgl1-mesa-glx`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Did you ran `sudo apt-get update`? Include the output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-gl`.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem with http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121036

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opencpn/opencpn
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opencpn
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted, this PPA actually had the fix that's allowed steam to work for me now.. 3 years later.